# Сравнивание пользователей GitHub

Tags: java, android, github, retrofit

Здравствуйте. 
Требуется получить по запросу данные двух случайных пользователей Github.
Запрашиваю страницу у GitHub в [таком виде](http://api.github.com/users?since=434) . Использую Retrofit. 
В интерфейсе описываю запрос в таком виде

```
@GET("/user?since/{number}")
Call<GithubUser>[] getListOfUsers(@Path("number") int number);
```

GithubUser описан в виде POJO для одного пользователя.

Подскажите как получить результат запроса в виде массива типа GithubUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@GET("/user?since/{number}")
Call<List<GithubUser>> getListOfUsers(@Path("number") int number);
```

так вот

```
Call<List<GithubUser>> result = httpApi.getListOfUsers(number);
    result.enqueue(new Callback<List<GithubUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<GithubUser>> call, Response<List<GithubUser>> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<GithubUser>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Пробовал, но получая список, затем его эл-т и вызывая для него enqueue() - приложение крашится.

Comment: Изменил, посмотрите

Comment: Когда я в getListOfUsers(number) подставляю случайное число, я ожидаю что в методе onResponse я получу список из новых пользователей чей id выше чем number.
Но ничего не получается.. я получаю всего один и тот же список. хотя number каждый раз разный. Подскажите, где зарыта собака?) 
P.S
запрос описываю таким образом 
@GET("/users?since")
    Call<List<GithubUser>> getListOfUsers(@Query("number") int number); 
иначе - приложение крашится c ошибкой - "ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "since={number}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query."

Comment: Заведите лучше новый вопрос. А так надо бы апи Github посмотреть.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Call<GithubUser>call = service.getListOfUsers(54).get(4);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<GithubUser>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GithubUser> call, Response<GithubUser> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        userData1.setText(response.body().getId().toString());

                 } else {}
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GithubUser> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

//или так

```
final List<Call<GithubUser>> call = service.getListOfUsers(54);
            call.get(4).enqueue(new Callback<GithubUser>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GithubUser> call, Response<GithubUser> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        userData1.setText(response.body().getId().toString());

                    } else {
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GithubUser> call, Throwable t) {
                }
            });


        }
    });
```